# Upload one image but save/export to multiple formats

Tags: files, media

Have been searching for this quite some time but I can't seem to find an answer. There must be someone who has encountered this before.

What I want to do is have an editor upload 1 image and then save/export it to multiple formats. Automatically save a thumbnail, smaller teaser version and a version that has a color filter. I don't want to create 3 upload fields and have the editor choose a filter.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Drupapl 7 then in Admin You would see Image Style. Once you are there you can define different presets such as thumbnail, large, medium etc. There are three predefined presets available. But you can add your own with the dimensions of your choice. Once you set that you can use that where ever you display in the image.

In views or fields display management with in the content type.

For advanced filters you should look into the [imagecache actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I didn't notice that it would automatically export all those predefined styles. Imagecache works great indeed. In a template you can just get the image style you want then.